# Langchain combine OpenAI function calling and Retrievers

Tags: javascript, openai-api, langchain

I want to implement a chatbot that can simultaneously respond with data from a web page and perform OpenAI functions. I have managed to develop OpenAI functions or the chatbot separately but unfortunately I cannot combine both behaviors.

I have attached my code below. Maybe someone can help me here. Thanks in advance.

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

import { ChatOpenAI } from "langchain/chat_models/openai";
import { ChatPromptTemplate } from "langchain/prompts";
import { CheerioWebBaseLoader } from "langchain/document_loaders/web/cheerio";
import { RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter } from "langchain/text_splitter";
import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai";
import { MemoryVectorStore } from "langchain/vectorstores/memory";
import { BufferMemory } from "langchain/memory";
import { RunnableSequence } from 'langchain/schema/runnable';


const loader = new CheerioWebBaseLoader(process.env.WEBSITE_URL);

const data = await loader.load();

const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({
    chunkSize: 500,
    chunkOverlap: 0,
});

const splitDocs = await textSplitter.splitDocuments(data);



const vectorStore = await MemoryVectorStore.fromDocuments(
    splitDocs,
    new OpenAIEmbeddings()
);

const retriever = vectorStore.asRetriever();




const memory = new BufferMemory({
    memoryKey: "chat_history",
    returnMessages: true,
});


const appointmentSchema = {
    "name": "create_appointment",
    "description": "use when the user wants to create an appointment",
    "parameters": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "date": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "date of the appointment in this format: 2021-10-10",
            },
            "time": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "time of the appointment in this format: 15:00",
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "date", "time"
        ]
    }
}

const template = `You are an assistent that answers the users question. When the user wants to book an appointment run the function. Todays date ist {date}`;

const humanTemplate = "{text}";

const chatPrompt = ChatPromptTemplate.fromMessages([
    ["system", template],
    ["human", humanTemplate],
]);

const model = new ChatOpenAI({ modelName: "gpt-4" }).bind({
    functions: [appointmentSchema],
    //function_call: { name: "create_appointment" },
});

//const chain = chatPrompt.pipe(model)
const chain = RunnableSequence.from([
    chatPrompt,
    model,
]);

let yourDate = new Date()

const result = await chain.invoke({
    text: "When do you open on mondays?",
    //text: "Book a appointment tomorrow 15:00",
    date: new Date(yourDate).toISOString().split('T')[0]
});


if (result.content) {
    console.log("Answer: " + result.content);
}
else {
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: what is `OpenAI functions` ?

Comment: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/function-calling